# How to deploy AWS resources across all regions via terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I need to deploy AWS GuardDuty across all accounts/regions in my AWS Organization.
My first step is to delegate GuardDuty's administration to a designated account. Since, GuardDuty is a regional resource, I need to perform such delegation across all regions. Note that we are operating in pretty much every region of AWS.

Here is a brute-force approach for accomplishing this task:

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-1"
  alias   = "us-east-1"
}
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-2"
  alias   = "us-east-2"
}
# Do the same for the remaining regions

resource "aws_guardduty_organization_admin_account" "us-east-1" {
   provider = aws.us-east-1
   admin_account_id = "123456789..."
}
resource "aws_guardduty_organization_admin_account" "us-east-2" {
 provider = aws.us-east-2
 admin_account_id = "123456789..."
}

# Do the same for the remaining regions
```

This works, but has several disadvantages:

- A lot of repetition
- I need to remember to update this code when a new region is added

Question: Is there a better way of doing this?
There is an old thread on this scenario here:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/451

However, it does not appear that a good options existed at that time, so I want to see if better options are available now.

Ideally, I want to leverage `data "aws_regions" "all" {}` to loop over the existing regions and dynamically create the delegation resources and providers.

I tried the approach suggested by @Matt Schuchard:

Given this resource:

```
resource "aws_guardduty_organization_admin_account" "us-east-1" {
  # interpolate in for expression here since not allowed in provider argument
  for_each = toset([for region in data.aws_regions.this.names : "aws.${region}"])

  provider         = each.value
  admin_account_id = "123456789..."
}
```

Terraform 1.0.10, produces the following error:

```
Error: Failed to query available provider packages
Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/each: ...
```

Comment: You can do this for the resources, but according to the roadmap this is still in development for the provider. If that is ok, I can write up the corresponding answer.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, yes please provide an answer for the resource part.

Answer (score 2):

You would need the `for_each` meta-argument for both the `provider` and the `resource` blocks to iterate over all AWS regions within a single block. If one attempts to use the `for_each` meta-argument with the `provider` block, then the error message displays:

> The provider argument name "for_each" is reserved for use by Terraform in a future version.

and this is on the roadmap for future development.

However, one can do this with the `for_each` meta-argument in the resource block. First, you suggested retrieving all available regions with the data `aws_regions` to always truly target all regions:

```
data "aws_regions" "this" {}
```

where the `all_regions` and `filters` arguments can down-select the desired regions. The exported resource attribute `names` of type `list(string)` would store the desired regions.

Assuming you are configuring providers and their aliases as described in the question, you would then use this `list` within the resource block:

```
resource "aws_guardduty_organization_admin_account" "us-east-1" {
  # interpolate in for expression here since not allowed in provider argument
  for_each = toset([for region in data.aws_regions.this.names : "aws.${region}"])

  provider         = each.value
  admin_account_id = "123456789..."
}
```

and this would manage the resource in all desired AWS regions.

Comment: Would it need to be `provider = "aws.${each.value}"` ?

Comment: @immutableT Yes, I was checking on the `ids` exported attribute to see if that should be used in the string interpolation instead and ended up distracting myself.

Comment: It does not appear the interpolation is supported by providers.

Comment: @immutableT I did not update my local test after the interpolation, so I missed that issue. You can just do the interpolation in a `for` expression in the meta-argument. Updating answer again.

Comment: I think you may need to update the provider assignment as well (in your last edit).
Unless I misunderstand your approach, you probably meant something like
`for_each = toset([for region in data.aws_regions.this.names : "aws.${region}"])`

`provider = each.key`

Comment: @immutableT Right, I had `each.value` in my local test and forgot to port it to the answer. As a side note, whereas `each.key` is valid here, it is recommended not to use that temporary lambda scope iterator variable in an iterated `set`.

Comment: As per `toset()` function: I thought in my notes that the `list` constructor in a `for` expression implicitly recasts to a `tuple` or `set` in `resource` scope where necessary, but a doublecheck confirms that is not true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239044/discussion-between-immutablet-and-matt-schuchard).

Comment: This definitely does not work @immutableT did you get this working?